# Ruby find which files or directories need to be uploaded: undefined local variable or method `dir' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, file, ssh, sftp

Everything is working up until line 36 where I am trying to define local_file. I am not sure what should go in addition to #{file} in local_file to make this work. I attempt to find which files or directories need to be uploaded by comparing their timestamps or if they exist. I know dir is not defined but I'm confused on what it should be, or if this is the right approach or scalable. What I could use is suggestions on the functionality, or a simple way to repair what i've got. Thank you for your help!

When I run this I get:

box.ru:36:in `block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method`dir' for main:Object (NameError)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/sftp'
require 'highline/import'
require 'find'


host = 'server'
local_path = '/Users/awesome1/Development/box'
remote_path = '/home/awesome2/box'

def sanitize_string(string_name)
string_name.gsub(/[^\w\.\-]/,"_")
end


puts "box username:"
user0 = gets.chomp
user = sanitize_string(user0)

pass0 = ask("Enter password for #{user}: ") { |q| q.echo = false }
pass = sanitize_string(pass0)

puts 'connecting to box...'
Net::SSH.start( host, user, :password => pass ) do|ssh|
result = ssh.exec!("cd #{remote_path} && ls")
 puts result
   ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp| 
 puts 'Checking for files which need updating'
 Find.find(local_path) do |file|
     next if File.stat(file).directory?
     local_file = "#{dir}/#{file}"
     remote_file = remote_path + local_file.sub(local_path, '')

     begin
     remote_dir = File.dirname(remote_file)
     sftp.stat(remote_dir)
 rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
   raise unless e.code == 2
   sftp.mkdir(remote_dir, :mode => dir_perm)
 end 
   begin
   rstat = sftp.stat(remote_file)
 rescue Net::SFTP::Operations::StatusException => e
   raise unless e.code == 2
   sftp.put_file(local_file, remote_file)
   sftp.setstat(remote_file, :permissions => file_perm)
   next
 end

 if File.stat(local_file).mtime > Time.at(rstat.mtime)
   puts "Copying #{local_file} to #{remote_file}"
   ssh.sftp.upload(local_file, remote_file)
  end
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear: You referred to an `undefined variable or method dir` on line 36.

```
  ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp| 
    puts 'Checking for files which need updating'
    Find.find(local_path) do |file|
      next if File.stat(file).directory?
      local_file = "#{dir}/#{file}"        # where does dir come from?
```

Update the error line to (or just reuse `file`)

```
local_file = file
```

because `Find` will yield filenames with the `local_path` prepended.